# r- ggplot decrease number of intervals of axis or spacing the axe tiks

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, axis

I've made a group plot of time series with ggplot with this syntax:

```
ggplot(Tur_flow, aes(x=time, group=parameter, colour=parameter))
    + geom_point(aes(y=value), size=1)
    + stat_smooth(aes(y=value), method=lm)
    + facet_grid(parameter ~ Section, scale="free_y")
    + theme_minimal()
    + theme(text = element_text(size=16))

dput(head(Tur_flow))
structure(list(Section = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S-5", "S-50", "S+5", "S+50"), class = "factor"), parameter = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Discharge", "Mean_Velocity", 
"T_15", "T_25", "T_65", "Water_Depth"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 34L, 41L), .Label = c("11:59:55", "11:59:56", 
"11:59:58", "11:59:59", "12:00:00", "12:00:02", "12:00:05", "12:00:55", 
"12:00:56", "12:00:58", "12:00:59", "12:01:00", "12:01:01", "12:01:05", 
"12:01:55", "12:01:56............. "8.30", "8.31", "8.41", "8.54", "8.94", "800.31", "822.01", "828.77", "839.30", "846.11", "847.60", "8497.25", "894.21", "91.66", "91.67", "91.68", "91.90", "92.08", "92.23", "92.54", "93.23", "974.50", "N/A"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Section", "parameter", 
"time", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Plot example]

1. How can I reduce the interval of both x and y axis? I mean spacing the axes? The x_axis data is time?
2. On y-axis how can I reduce decimal numbers?

Comment: Are by any change your variables factors while you think they're numeric?

Comment: Place the output of `dput(head(Tur_flow))` in your question or make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423) with sample data or something...

Comment: @Heroka, I didn't understand you? I'm sorry

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput` as JasonAizkalns suggested? Your plot looks likes your variables are not numeric, so ggplot (which is usually very good at scaling scales for lack of a better word) plots all the labels.

Comment: Put the dput in the question please.

Comment: Do `Tur_Flow$value = as.numeric(as.character(Tur_Flow$value))`.

Comment: Thanks alot @Gregor it works!